# Using React Hooks with AWS Cognito for auth

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, amazon-cognito

I'm using the hook below for auth with AWS Cognito. When a user signs in, it doesn't run and therefore React thinks the user is still not authenticated. If I refresh the page, everything works as it should. What am I doing wrong?

```
import { useState, useEffect, useMemo } from "react";
import { Auth } from "aws-amplify";

interface User {
  email: string;
  id: string;
  isAuthenticated: boolean;
  loading: boolean;
}

const useAuth = () => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState<User>({
    email: "",
    id: "",
    isAuthenticated: false,
    loading: true,
  });

  const auth = useMemo(() => {
    Auth.configure({
      userPoolId: process.env.REACT_APP_COGNITO_USER_POOL_ID,
      userPoolWebClientId: process.env.REACT_APP_COGNITO_APP_CLIENT_ID,
    });
    return Auth;
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    const checkUser = async () => {
      try {
        const user = await auth.currentAuthenticatedUser();
        setUser({
          email: user.attributes.email,
          id: user.attributes.sub,
          isAuthenticated: true,
          loading: false,
        });
        return null;
      } catch (e) {
        setUser({
          email: "",
          id: "",
          isAuthenticated: false,
          loading: false,
        });
        return null;
      }
    };
    checkUser();
  }, []);
  return user;
};

export default useAuth;
```